# Confused with change of representations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The book I'm reading got me confused with how change of representations work. Consider the following excerpt [image]
To me it looks like **T** would convert from representations in the original frame to representations in the *(u,v,n,p)* and **C** would do otherwise. Hence,
$$C \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \boldsymbol{u} = \begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\\ u_3\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Why is it not the case?

Comment: With $a=Cb$ you have a representation (b) in the first frame and obtain a representation (a) in the second frame. So $T=C^{-1}$ works (when you use $d=Tc$) with representations (c) in the secon frame.

Comment: @Ripi2 I guess what got me confused is that I thought that $a$ is representation in the original frame, and $b$ is representation in the new frame.